# How can I use animate.css with animation.fill.mode?

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

I have a simple example in which an image fades in when a button is clicked. I want the image to stay after the fadeIn-animation is done and tried to do so with animation-fill-mode: forwards. However, that doesn't work. I'd be very thankful for a short hint.

This is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Animate.css!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.css">
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" class="button" id="first">Hola!</a>
<img src="tucan.png" id="tucan" alt="Tucan">

<style type="text/css">
    body {
        margin: 50px;
        background: #2980b9;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
    }

    a.button {
        background:#e74c3c;
        color: white;
        padding: 20px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 50px;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

    #tucan {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }



</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var animationName = 'animated fadeIn';
var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';

$(function(){
    $('#first').on('click',function(){
        $('#tucan').addClass(animationName).one(animationEnd, function (){
                $(this).removeClass(animationName);
        });
    });
});


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
$('#first').on('click',function(){
    $('#tucan').addClass(animationName).one(animationEnd, function (){
            $(this).removeClass(animationName);
            $(this).css( "opacity", 1 );
    });
});
```

or try

```
$('#first').on('click',function(){
    $('#tucan').addClass(animationName);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tried it, but unfortunately - and for some reason I do not understand - it doesn't work either. Looks like I've made a mistake somewhere else, because I found an example on jsfiddle that does exactly what I want and is pretty straightforward: http://fiddle.jshell.net/rcorp/TGPtG/1/light/

Comment: so you just want the image to stay after fadeIn? why animationEnd ? The removeClass, will set the #tuncan opacity to '0' (original state as in css) once it has been removed, if you want to remove the class, then set #tuncan opacity to 1,